# Grouping irregular timestamp data and label according to Group

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have incoming data at irregular time intervals. Useful information is decoded when group the data according to 120seconds but the start time is not fixed. Example df below.

```
    TIME                SPEED
0   19-01-18 10:25:43   1425
1   19-01-18 10:25:45   1425
2   19-01-18 10:25:46   1425
3   22-12-18 23:25:56   1435
4   23-12-18 00:00:15   1433
5   29-10-18 00:37:15   1388
6   29-10-18 00:39:18   1388
7   29-10-18 00:39:40   1388
```

Q1) Can Pandas group the timestamp according to user's interval for example 120 seconds in this case ; and Q2) label them accordingly like below:

```
    TIME                SPEED   Group
0   19-01-18 10:25:43   1425      1
1   19-01-18 10:25:45   1425      1
2   19-01-18 10:25:46   1425      1
3   22-12-18 23:25:56   1435      2
4   23-12-18 00:00:15   1433      2
5   29-10-18 00:37:15   1388      3
6   29-10-18 00:39:18   1388      4
7   29-10-18 00:39:40   1388      4
```

So the first cycle/group starts at 19-01-18 10:25:43. Any data within 120s, will be grouped together. The second cycle will start at the next available timestamp (22-12-18 23:25:56) and 120s from the timestamp. The process will continue.
Any tips if very much appreciated.

Comment: Look at rows with *Group == 2*. The first was recorded on *22-12-18 20:25:56* and the second on *23-12-18 00:00:15*.
If they are about 3 h 30 min apart (**much** more than 120 s), why did you decide to include them in the same group?

Comment: Sorry. The #3 data should be 3   22-12-18 23:25:56   1435

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas.Grouper` with `ngroup`:

```
import pandas as pd

df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], dayfirst=True)
s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='TIME', freq='120s')).ngroup()
df['Group'] = s.groupby(s).ngroup().add(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 TIME  SPEED  Group
0 2018-01-19 10:25:43   1425      1
1 2018-01-19 10:25:45   1425      1
2 2018-01-19 10:25:46   1425      1
3 2018-12-22 20:25:56   1435      4
4 2018-12-23 00:00:15   1433      5
5 2018-10-29 00:37:15   1388      2
6 2018-10-29 00:39:18   1388      3
7 2018-10-29 00:39:40   1388      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) or [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], dayfirst=True)

df['G'] = pd.factorize(df['TIME'].dt.floor('120S'))[0] + 1
print (df)
                 TIME  SPEED  G
0 2018-01-19 10:25:43   1425  1
1 2018-01-19 10:25:45   1425  1
2 2018-01-19 10:25:46   1425  1
3 2018-12-22 20:25:56   1435  2
4 2018-12-23 00:00:15   1433  3
5 2018-10-29 00:37:15   1388  4
6 2018-10-29 00:39:18   1388  5
7 2018-10-29 00:39:40   1388  5
```

---

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], dayfirst=True)

df['G'] = df['TIME'].dt.floor('120S').rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
                 TIME  SPEED  G
0 2018-01-19 10:25:43   1425  1
1 2018-01-19 10:25:45   1425  1
2 2018-01-19 10:25:46   1425  1
3 2018-12-22 20:25:56   1435  4
4 2018-12-23 00:00:15   1433  5
5 2018-10-29 00:37:15   1388  2
6 2018-10-29 00:39:18   1388  3
7 2018-10-29 00:39:40   1388  3
```